# Expectation of an affine transformation $AX+b$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-variables, expected-value

I'm wondering how come ($A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$; $b \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times 1}$; $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times 1}$ is a vector):

$$
\mathbb{E}[A \, \boldsymbol{X} + \boldsymbol{b}] = A \mathbb{E}[X] + b
$$

I know that the ith component of the vector $A \, \boldsymbol{X} + \boldsymbol{b}$ is:

$$
(A \, \boldsymbol{X} + \boldsymbol{b})_i = \left( \sum \limits _{l = 1}^{d} A_{i \, l} \, X_l \right) + b_i
$$

---

EDIT

I tried in this way:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[A \, \boldsymbol{X} + \boldsymbol{b}] &=
\left(
\mathbb{E}\left[\left( \sum \limits _{l = 1}^{d} A_{1 \, l} \, X_l \right) + b_1\right]
\quad ... \quad
\mathbb{E}\left[\left( \sum \limits _{l = 1}^{d} A_{k \, l} \, X_l \right) + b_k\right]
\right) = \\
&= \left(
\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum \limits _{l = 1}^{d} A_{1 \, l} \, X_l\right] + b_1
\quad ... \quad
\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum \limits _{l = 1}^{d} A_{k \, l} \, X_l \right] + b_k
\right) = \\
&= \left(
\sum \limits _{l = 1}^{d} \mathbb{E}\left[ A_{1 \, l} \, X_l \right] + b_1
\quad ... \quad
\sum \limits _{l = 1}^{d} \mathbb{E}\left[ A_{k \, l} \, X_l \right] + b_k
\right) = \\
&= \left(
\sum \limits _{l = 1}^{d} A_{1 \, l} \, \mathbb{E}\left[ X_l \right] + b_1
\quad ... \quad
\sum \limits _{l = 1}^{d} A_{k \, l} \, \mathbb{E}\left[ X_l \right] + b_k
\right)
\end{align}

and now I'm stuck.

Comment: Expected value is an integral, and the integral is linear.

Comment: Hello @Berci I'm trying to d it by applying the properties of the expectation.

Comment: It's fine. Observe that $\Bbb E[X]=(\Bbb E[X_1],\dots,\Bbb E[X_d])^T$.